# How to use regex substitution between two different "no whitespace" patterns in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove everything in between `<` and `>`, but only if `<` is not followed by a space and `>` does not have a space before it. For example, `<a>` should be removed but `< a>` and `<a >` should not.

So far, I have this:

```
cleanText = re.sub('<[^>]+>', ' ', text)
```

This works, except I'm not sure how to approach the no white space rule.

At the moment, the input:

```
txt = "<this should be removed> hello < world > </this should also be removed> this should stay"
```

returns:

```
  hello     this should stay
```

while I would like it to return:

```
  hello < world >    this should stay
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use negative lookahed and lookbehing after the opening and before the closing characters:

```
r'<(?!\s)([^>]*)?(?<!\s)>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may convert matches of the following regular expression to empty strings.

```
(?<=<(?!\s))[^<>]*?(?=(?<!\s)>)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cnqa5g/1)

This expression has the following elements.

```
(?<=       Begin a negative lookbehind
  <        Match a literal
  (?!\s)   Use a negative lookahead to assert that the previous
           match is not followed by a whitespace character
)          End negative lookbehind
[^<>]*
?          Require previous match to match as few characters as possible
(?=        Begin a positive lookahead
  (?<!\s)  Use a negative lookbehind to assert that the following
           match is not preceded by a whitespace character
  >        Match a literal
)          End the positive lookahead
```

Answer (score 1):

You could match:

```
<[^<>\s](?:[^<>]*[^<>\s])?>
```

**Explanation**

- `<` Match literally
- `[^<>\s]` Match a single char other than `<` `>` or a whitespace char
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[^<>]*` Match 0+ chars other than `<` or `>`
  - `[^<>\s]` Match a single char other than `<` `>` or a whitespace char
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional
- `>` Match literally

In the replacement use an empty string.

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a0WuSo/1).

```
import re
 
pattern = r"<[^<>\s](?:[^<>]*[^<>\s])?>"
txt = "<this should be removed> hello < world > </this should also be removed> this should stay"
result = re.sub(pattern, "", txt)
 
if result:
    print (result)
```

Output

```
 hello < world >  this should stay
```

If you want the empty `<>` then you can use that [in the replacement](https://ideone.com/KNOuji).

Comment: That's clever to remove the `'<'` and `'>'` and then (in part 2) add them back in. The demo in my answer took 159 steps. Your regex with the same example [took 26 steps](https://regex101.com/r/JmAJe0/1) (as I expected)! @AlainT., your regex [took 46 steps](https://regex101.com/r/Oua3VV/1) to match and capture the string to be replaced with an empty string.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks, I am always careful when it comes to less steps vs execution time of the code. I think one should measure the execution of the code with different payloads to have more realistic view of the performance.

Comment: Yes, but one should be able to guess that having a positive lookahead within a negative lookbehind (as I have) is going to be step-intensive, but one should also be able to guess that, depending on the application, that may not matter (but it may still rankle one's sensibilities).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this: `/<\S[^>]*>/g`:

```js
const text = '<this should be removed> hello < world > </this should also be removed> this should stay';
const result = text.replace(/<\S[^>]*>/g, '');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Are you sure that this works in the same way in Python?

Comment: @mkrieger1 regex is works [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5Jzaft/1). JavaScript code snippet is written for demonstration purposes only.